# Azure AD App-Only Authentication in an ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-ad-graph-api

Most of the examples for ASP.NET Core WebAPIs I have seen are leveraging the authentication 'middleware', which get added in the Startup file and it seems to make the code very elegant.  However I am not authenticating the user in any way, instead I'm using [Azure AD App-Only](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azuread) to access Graph and SharePoint REST API's.  And I cannot find any decent examples showing me how to leverage the 'middleware' without logging in a user.

The only example I could find was [this one](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2015/12/14/implementing-application-with-o365-graph-api-in-app-only-mode/), and below is what I have come up with. My technique works but it seems a bit novice, and I'm wondering if there is a way to make App-Only authentication work within the native Core authentication/identity toolset?

```
public class ExclusionRequestsController : Controller
{
    private readonly IConfiguration Config;
    private string token;
    public ExclusionRequestsController(IConfiguration config)
    {
        Config = config;
        this.Init();

    }
    private async void Init()
    {
        string certFile = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + Config["BIS232AppSettings:CertificatePath"]);
        X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(certFile, Config["BIS232AppSettings:CertificatePassword"], X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
        AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(String.Format("{0}{1}/oauth2/authorize",
            Config["BIS232AppSettings:Instance"],
            Config["BIS232AppSettings:TenantID"]), false);
        ClientAssertionCertificate cac = new ClientAssertionCertificate(Config["BIS232AppSettings:ClientID"], certificate);
        var authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(Config["BIS232AppSettings:GraphResourceId"], cac);
        this.token = authenticationResult.AccessToken;
    }

    // GET: api/ExclusionRequests/Get
    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("Get")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<dynamic>> Get()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", this.token);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        string requestUrl = Config["BIS232AppSettings:GraphResourceId"] + "v1.0/sites/" + Config["BIS232AppSettings:Hostname"] + ","
            + Config["BIS232AppSettings:SPSiteID"] + "," + Config["BIS232AppSettings:SPWebID"] + "/lists/"
            + Config["BIS232AppSettings:ERList"] + "/items?expand=Fields&$top=50";

        HttpResponseMessage result = await client.GetAsync(requestUrl);
        if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string json = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
        }
        else
            return new NoContentResult();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to authenticate your user in other project like share point?